# Octave Showing Weird Output and Command Window not working

Tags: command, output, window, octave

i Know i don't do something dumb, cause im working with Octave for years now.
I installed it on my new computer and the command window showed a weird output of differrent colored symbols. I installed 7.1 back than.

I tried 8.3 afterwards. There was no weird output, but the command window wasnt working either. Even a=1 didnt work as a test.
So i tried 7.3, cause thats the Version im used to at work, and there, the same different Output is shown. [Weird Output in Command Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUyRW.png)

Would love to get some help!
Im thinking at could be an error caused bei UTF-8 or something like this.

Comment: This may be related to the new terminal app on Windows 11. See [here](https://octave.discourse.group/t/workaround-for-weird-behavior-of-command-window-widget-in-windows/4981) for workaround.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Currently, Octave is not *fully compatible* with the new "Windows Terminal App" (which become the default console in Windows 11).

During Octave installation you should see the following [warning](https://hg.octave.org/mxe-octave/rev/4f25eb25a80b):

> Octave doesn't work correctly when the default console on Windows is set to the new Terminal app. Check if the default is set to the Windows Console Host and show advice if it is not.

### Consequences

This unsupported configuration could lead to unexpected behavior of the Octave CLI like the "weird" characters and colors mentioned in your question.

Also, you can have [both CLI and command window opened simultaneously](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?62791) and displaying exactly the same content (you could also observe strange text overlap and difficulty to scroll-up/down).

### Workaround

As stated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490853/octave-showing-weird-output-and-command-window-not-working#comment136613331_77490853), a workaround consists of setting the "Windows Console Host" (i.e. the old cmd.exe console) as the default windows console (see screenshot of the settings screen below) [[from here](https://octave.discourse.group/t/workaround-for-weird-behavior-of-command-window-widget-in-windows/4981)].
A way to access this setting is to type "terminal" in the Windows search box and select "Choose a terminal host app for interactive command-line tools".

[image]

## Potential solution to come

A ["new cross-platform command window widget"](https://wiki.octave.org/GUI_terminal_widget) is currently in development and [may be able to solve this issue](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?62791#comment3).