# Octave GUI 8.4.0 starts always with powershell window (Windows 11, Admin rights)

Tags: powershell, user-interface, octave

When starting Octave GUI 8.4.0 (Windows 11) an additional Powershell window always opens. When i close this window, octace closes, too. If I open Octave with admin rights this doesn't happen.

Anyone have any ideas?

i tried to install octave for only me and all users. no change.

Comment: if you are using windows 11, are you using the new Windows Terminal? the symptoms you mention sound similar to those issues, as Octave is currently not compatible with that new terminal.  please see this page on the Octave discourse site for a workaround. https://octave.discourse.group/t/workaround-for-weird-behavior-of-command-window-widget-in-windows/4981

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490853/octave-showing-weird-output-and-command-window-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nick!

Switching to "Windows Console-Host" solved the problem...

https://octave.discourse.group/t/workaround-for-weird-behavior-of-command-window-widget-in-windows/4981

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).