Octave 9.2.0 crash
Good morning,
I have windows 11 with Octave 9.2.0 .
When I try to execute a script the program crashes everytime. I tried also with older version of Octave and it is the same. Could it be for a recent Windows update?
I saw that the problem is with the packet "io". I also tried to uninstall and install it again but also when I try to install the package the program crashes.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks
I would like to execute my script I already executed thousand times. I cannot understand what could be happened.

1 - you need to provide much more information for any useful code help.  does 'crash' mean the whole program crashes, or the code produces an error? what is the code you're executing?  can you provide the version of any packages you're using?     2 - if you're getting hard crashes of the application, this might be better reported to the Octave help list for direct developer assistance at octave.discourse.group but they'll need to know the same things i asked for above.


Last, do any other scripts cause issue? Are you using the new Windows Terminal and maybe it's not the script but a screen output buffer issue resulting in a crash? A number of odd behaviors, some including crashes some not, have been reported with the Windows Terminal.  see one example with workaround at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490853/octave-showing-weird-output-and-command-window-not-working


Hi,

The Octave GUI closes. I use Octave 9.2.0 with windows 11 23H2.
Ok, i will report it
Yes, any script. I attach the first part of the script that crashes already when try to load the "io package". I tried in debug


clear all;
close all;
pkg load io
try
%Carica i dati, tenendo in considerazione i numeri e il valore raw del file
[num, ~, raw] = xlsread("Discharge.xlsx");
%Prendi tutte le righe della seconda e la terza colonna
data = raw(:, [2, 3, 4]);
%Righe dove il valore della prima colonna è cambiato
change_rows = [true; diff(num(:, 1)) ~= 0];
output = data([true; change_rows], :);
last_row = raw(end, [2, 3, 4]);
output = [output; last_row];

Another information: I tried to uninstall "io" and now when I try to reinstall it , Octave crashes everytime...

The problem is only "pkg load io". It makes Octave crash!
